# trouble with using textFieldShouldEndEditing after my popover gets dismissed

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I'm bringing up a popover that has a field in it. I'm using "textFieldShouldEndEditing" to do some validation of the text. If the entered text is invalid, I return "NO".

The problem when I dismiss my popover. If the text is invalid, textFieldShouldEndEditing returns "NO". After I dismiss my popover, and click in any other text field, the field doesn't not get selected. I can't type in any other field, the keyboard doesn't show up.

What's the best way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Try using [textField resignFirstResponder] before returning NO.

Comment: Didn't work. But here's the weird thing. I found this routine on UIView -(BOOL)endEditing:(BOOL)force.  I would've thought that this would, you know, force the responder chain to stop editing. Which it says it does in the docs, but doesn't in real life. If it's forcing it to end, my "textFieldShouldEndEditing" call probably shouldn't even be called right? It sounded like the solution, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to achieve, but I'm thinking you can put some checks in when you're dismissing the popover.

```
-(void)dimissView
{
    //We already know we are going to dismiss the view right away, so we can set
    //[textField resignFirstResponder];, no matter if the text is valid or not

    if(textView.text is valid)//Create some condition
    {
        //tell the parentView that textField.text was valid
    }
    else
    {
        //Tell the parentView that textField.text was invalid   
    }

    [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When you've found a way to tell the parent of the popover that the textField was invalid, I.E setting a `bool textFieldTextWasValid = NO;`, then you can easily check, and make the appropriate behavior for when you're trying to select another textView in the parent, or whatever your case was.

Beware, this is not working code, this is just an idea, and you need to understand it to make it work.